# Finding the best divider using integer arithmetic

Tags: integer-division, integer-arithmetic

We often have to find divider values in our clock framework which generate a clock rate *closest* to the target rate, i.e. `ABS(target_rate - input_rate / best_div)` should be minimal.  We are limited to integer arithmetic and use the following formula:

```
int best_div, input_rate, target_rate;
best_div = (input_rate + target_rate / 2) / target_rate;
```

We can safely assume that `input_rate >= target_rate`, `input_rate > 0`, and `target_rate > 0`.

However, there are some numbers for which the formula "fails", e.g. `input_rate = 12152131, target_rate = 441992`.  For those numbers the formula will return `best_div = 27` whereas `28` would result in a rate closer to `441992`.

This leads to two questions:

1. Why is the formula not correct in this case?
2. I there a fail-safe formula for finding the best divider? Obviously one could just compute the resulting frequency for both dividers, `input_rate / target_rate` and `input_rate / target_rate + 1` and choose the better one but a simpler, direct formula would be preferred.

Comment: If `q = (input_rate / target_rate) + i` (using integer division, and with `i` in {0,1}), your current formula minimizes  `abs (input_rate - target_rate * q)`, whereas you want to minimize `abs (target_rate - input_rate / q)`, where the division is again integer division. Because of the truncating nature of integer division, the two formulas are *not* equivalent.

Comment: I think this question belongs to math.stackexchange.com, because it primarily tries to solve a mathematical problem instead of a programming problem.